# How to compare a then add a specific object's filed in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Everytime I hit the botton I add an ID to the cookies, so the value (correspond with the ID) could be duplicate. Then I read in Express all the elements (in the model is called price, so works.price from MongoDB and the cookies.
My goal is to pass the data in PUG where there is the list of elements from MongoDB without the duplicates but with the sum of works.price present in the mongoDB element.

```
exports.getcart = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const works = await Work.find();
const cookies = req.cookies;
const fullUrl = req.protocol + `://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`;

const urlCookie = fullUrl.split('/')[2];
delete cookies['urlCookie'];

let value = {};
let items = [];
let id = [];
let counts = {};

for (let key in cookies) {
    const work = await Work.findById({ _id: cookies[key] });
    items.push(value.work = work);
    id.push(cookies[key]);
}
const unique = [...new Set(id)];
id.forEach(function (x) {
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;

});
console.log(items);
console.log(unique);
console.log(id);



// console.log(counts);

res.status(200).render('page', {
    title: 'page',
    <OBJECT?>
    });
});
```

This id the console.log of what I'm doing.
in the array I called items there is the array of object with the same ID present in the cookies.

```
console.log(unique);
    [
  '5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94',
  '5eb19f3bad682508dc024301',
  '5eb568d4c60f2471684ee9fb'
]

console.log(id);
[
  '5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94',
  '5eb19f3bad682508dc024301',
  '5eb19f3bad682508dc024301',
  '5eb568d4c60f2471684ee9fb',
  '5eb568d4c60f2471684ee9fb',
  '5eb19f3bad682508dc024301',
  '5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94'
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. What is the output you've shown meant to be?

Comment: console.log(unique); are the unique id I want to render, and console.log(id); are all the id in the cookies. The problem is that in PUG I didn't achive to make the sum of all duplicates in the element from mongdDB rendered.

Comment: For example this ID is present two times in the cookies '5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94', I want to show it just once, but in the field works.price I need to put the sum because is present twice. I hope it is clear

Comment: @Jack Bashford do you have any where I can check to solve this problem? Thanks